# Metrizing pointwise convergence of *sequences* of functionals in a dual space.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed, real vector space of uncountable dimension. Let $X^*$ denote the set of all continuous linear functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a metric $d : X^* \times X^* \to \mathbb{R}$ such that a sequence $(\varphi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $X^*$ converges to $\varphi$ with respect to $d$ if and only if $\varphi_n(x) \to \varphi(x)$ for all $x \in X$?

I believe the answer to this question is no, but I have been unable to show it.

I am aware that "the topology of pointwise convergence" -- the weak* topology -- is not metrizable. However, there exist distinct topologies which agree on their convergent sequences, so it is possible for such a metric to exist while still inducing a different topology from the weak* topology.

I have seen [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435469/conditions-that-ensure-the-metric-topology-of-e-coincides-with-the-initial-top) which asks a more general question about when the metric topology agrees with the weak topology induced by a family of functions. The answer to this question presents sufficient conditions; I am interested in necessary conditions.

Here's what I know:

- If $X$ has *countable* dimension, then there *does* exist a metric which does this: namely, $d(\varphi, \psi) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{|\varphi(x_n) - \psi(x_n)|}{|\varphi(x_n) - \psi(x_n)|+1}$ where $\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a linear basis of $X$.
- Pointwise convergence on every basis vector implies pointwise convergence everywhere. So, the question may equivalently be stated: "does there exist a metric $d : X^* \times X^* \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi_n \to_d \phi$ if and only if $\phi_n(x_i) \to \phi(x_i)$ for all basis vectors $x_i$?"
- When $X$ is separable, such a metric exists on the unit ball (with respect to the operator norm) of $X^*$.

I have tried (without success) to reduce the problem to that of the metrizability of the weak* topology by arguing that any metric which satisfies the desired property must in fact induce the weak* topology. In particular, I have tried to show that the family of open sets $S = \left\{ e_x^{-1}(U) : x \in X, U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \text{ is open} \right\}$ is a subbase for the topology induced by $d$ (here, $e_x$ denotes the evaluation map $f \mapsto f(x)$).

I have also tried to directly derive a contradiction by constructing a sequence of functionals which must converge to zero but do not converge pointwise.